# Javascript assign Object inside Object dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, object

Here is my object sample, i need to loop through and assign dynamically {"type": "object"} inside every inner object.

Input:

var favoriteFruit = {
    "Amy": {
       "desc": "Amy's fav",
        "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Banana",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
        "Ben": {
           "desc": "Ben's fav",
           "fruit": {
                "Name" : "Apple",
                "color" : "Red"
             }
        },
        "Carol": {
            "desc": "Carol's fav",
            "fruit": {
                "Name" : "Cherry",
                "color" : "Red"
             }
        },
        "Olivia": {
            "desc": "Olivia fav",
            "fruit": {
                "Name" : "Orange",
                "color" : "Orange"
             }
        },
        "Pualine": {
            "desc": "Pualine fav",
            "fruit": {
                "Name" : "Pear",
                "color" : "Green"
             }
        }
    };

Expected output:

```
var favoriteFruit = {
    "Amy": {
       "type": "object", 
       "desc": "Amy's fav",
         "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Banana",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Ben": {
        "type": "object", 
        "desc": "Ben's fav",
         "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Apple",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Carol": {
        "type": "object",
        "desc": "Carol's fav", 
         "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Cherry",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Olivia": {
        "type": "object",
         "desc": "Olivia fav", 
         "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Orange",
            "color" : "Orange"
         }
    },
    "Pualine": {
        "type": "object", 
        "desc": "Pualine fav",
         "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Pear",
            "color" : "Green"
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That's not JSON. That's just a regular JavaScript object. JSON is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a JSON string, but I've quoted it so that it now is.

See comments inline:

```js
var favoriteFruit = `{
    "Amy": {
       "desc": "Amy's fav",
        "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Banana",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Ben": {
       "desc": "Ben's fav",
       "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Apple",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Carol": {
        "desc": "Carol's fav",
        "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Cherry",
            "color" : "Red"
         }
    },
    "Olivia": {
        "desc": "Olivia fav",
        "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Orange",
            "color" : "Orange"
         }
    },
    "Pualine": {
        "desc": "Pualine fav",
        "fruit": {
            "Name" : "Pear",
            "color" : "Green"
         }
    }
}`;

// Turn the JSON into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(favoriteFruit);

// Loop through the object's properties
for(var prop in obj){
   // Give each object a new property/value
   obj[prop].type = "Object";
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: is it possible to have that "type":"object" at the first position?      
    "Pualine": {    
 "type": "Object",                                                                                                          
    "desc": "Pualine fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Pear",
      "color": "Green"
    }
}

Comment: @user2553117 No, the sequence of properties in an object is never guranteed. And, frankly, there's no reason that you would ever need them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the keys, accessible by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then go from there using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var favoriteFruit = {
  "Amy": {
    "desc": "Amy's fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Banana",
      "color": "Red"
    }
  },
  "Ben": {
    "desc": "Ben's fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "color": "Red"
    }
  },
  "Carol": {
    "desc": "Carol's fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Cherry",
      "color": "Red"
    }
  },
  "Olivia": {
    "desc": "Olivia fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Orange",
      "color": "Orange"
    }
  },
  "Pualine": {
    "desc": "Pualine fav",
    "fruit": {
      "Name": "Pear",
      "color": "Green"
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(favoriteFruit).forEach(function (key) {
  Object.assign(favoriteFruit[key], { type: 'object' })
})

console.log(favoriteFruit)
```

If you really care about `type` being the first key when stringifying (though this is not guaranteed in the specification since keys are ultimately unordered), you can use this instead:

```
Object.keys(favoriteFruit).forEach(function (key) {
  favoriteFruit[key] = Object.assign({ type: 'object' }, favoriteFruit[key])
})
```